# extracting year from xs:date

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to display only the presidents from the 21st century in my output. How would I go about this in the xsl document? Do I need to use a namespace in the xml file and incorporate that into the .xsd and xsl file? How do I extract the date from the xs:date value?

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="president_21c.xsl"?>

<presidents xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="president.xsd" xmlns:president="http://www.du.edu/~mschwart/xml/president" date="2014-09-24">

    <president>
        <number>41</number>
        <name>George H. W. Bush</name>
         <birthday>1924-06-12</birthday>
        <took_office>1989-01-20</took_office>
        <left_office>1993-01-20</left_office>
        <party>Republican</party>
        <term>
            <term_number>51</term_number>
            <vice_president>Dan Quayle</vice_president>
        </term>
         <president_image>images/41.jpg</president_image>
    </president>

    <president>
        <number>42</number>
        <name>Bill Clinton</name>
         <birthday>1946-08-19</birthday>
        <took_office>1993-01-20</took_office>
        <left_office>2001-01-20</left_office>
        <party>Democratic</party>
        <term>
            <term_number>52</term_number>
            <vice_president>Al Gore</vice_president>
        </term>
        <term>
            <term_number>53</term_number>
            <vice_president>Al Gore</vice_president>
        </term>
         <president_image>images/42.jpg</president_image>
    </president>

    <president>
        <number>43</number>
        <name>George W. Bush</name>
         <birthday>1946-07-06</birthday>
        <took_office>2001-01-20</took_office>
        <left_office>2009-01-20</left_office>
        <party>Republican</party>
        <term>
            <term_number>54</term_number>
            <vice_president>Dick Cheney</vice_president>
        </term>
        <term>
            <term_number>55</term_number>
            <vice_president>Dick Cheney</vice_president>
        </term>
         <president_image>images/43.jpg</president_image>
    </president>

    <president>
        <number>44</number>
        <name>Barack Obama</name>
         <birthday>1961-08-04</birthday>
        <took_office>2009-01-20</took_office>
        <left_office xsi:nil="true"/>
        <party>Democratic</party>
        <term>
            <term_number>56</term_number>
            <vice_president>Joe Biden</vice_president>
        </term>
         <president_image>images/44.jpg</president_image>
    </president>
</presidents>
```

and my xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="html" version="4.0"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="president_21c.css"/>
    <title>Table of Us Presidents</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Table of Us Presidents</h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Birthday</th>
                <th>Took Office</th>
                <th>Left Office</th>
                <th>Party</th>
                <th>Vice President</th>
                <th>Portrait</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//president">
                <xsl:sort select="party"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="president">
<tr>
    <td><xsl:apply-templates select="name"/></td>
    <td><xsl:apply-templates select="birthday"/></td>
    <td><xsl:apply-templates select="took_office"/></td>
    <td><xsl:apply-templates select="left_office"/></td>
    <td><xsl:apply-templates select="party"/></td>
    <td>
    <xsl:for-each select="term">
        <xsl:number value="position()" format="1. " />
        <xsl:value-of select="vice_president" /><br />
    </xsl:for-each>
    </td>
    <td align="center" style="background-color: #E1E0E0;">
    <img src="{president_image}" class="president_image"/>
    </td>
</tr>
</xsl:template>



</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formal method to extract the year from a date is to use the [year-from-date() function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-year-from-date).

The informal method (which can often be more convenient) is to use:

```
substring-before(your-date, '-')
```

Comment: hmm k. So how do I implement this into my xsl document?

Comment: @esgg I could copy the example from the link above and paste it into my answer...

Answer (score 0):

For those who like to know how to use year-from-date:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"   
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  
  <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="president_21c.css"/>
        <title>Table of Us Presidents</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Table of Us Presidents</h1>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Birthday</th>
            <th>Took Office</th>
            <th>Left Office</th>
            <th>Party</th>
            <th>Vice President</th>
            <th>Portrait</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="presidents/president[left_office[@xsi:nil='true' or year-from-date(xs:date(.)) ge 2000 ]]">
            <xsl:sort select="party"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="president">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:apply-templates select="name"/></td>
      <td><xsl:apply-templates select="birthday"/></td>
      <td><xsl:apply-templates select="took_office"/></td>
      <td><xsl:apply-templates select="left_office"/></td>
      <td><xsl:apply-templates select="party"/></td>
      <td>
        <xsl:for-each select="term">
          <xsl:number value="position()" format="1. " />
          <xsl:value-of select="vice_president" /><br />
        </xsl:for-each>
      </td>
      <td align="center" style="background-color: #E1E0E0;">
        <img src="{president_image}" class="president_image"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```